# Why won't email send using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Does anyone know where I am going wrong with the code here? Might it be because I am using localhost to send? Or something else?

When I click the reset password button with an incorrect email the msg appears but when I input a correct email nothing shows and no email is sent. Using hotmail to send email, changed IMAP settings on email account.

PHP:

```html
include_once(ROOT_PATH . "/app/database/db.php");
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  global $conn;

  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $sql = $conn->query("SELECT u_id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
  if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {

    $token = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm1234567890£$%&?@!#";
    $token = str_shuffle($token);
    $token = substr($token, 0 , 20);

    $conn->query("UPDATE users SET token='$token',
      tokenExpire=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
      WHERE email='$email'");

      require_once(ROOT_PATH . "/app/includes/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php");
      require_once(ROOT_PATH . "/app/includes/phpmailer/Exception.php");

      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      $mail->SMPTDebug = 3;
      $mail->Host = "";
      $mail->SMPTAuth = true;
      $mail->Username = "********";
      $mail->Password = "********";
      $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
      $mail->Port = 587;
      $mail->addAddress($email);
      $mail->From("********");
      $mail->FromName = "Cath";
      $mail->Subject = "Reset Password";
      $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->smtpConnect(
        array(
          "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
            "allow_self_signed" => true
          )
        )
      );

      $mail->Body = "
        Hi,<br><br>

        In order to reset your password, please click on the link below:<br>
        <a href='
        http://localhost/weinspire/blog/resetPassword.php?email=$email&token=$token
        '>http://localhost/weinspire/blog/resetPassword.php?email=$email&token=$token</a><br><br>

        Thanks,<br><br>

        Seeing The New
      ";

      if($mail->send())
        exit(json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg" => 'Please check your email inbox.')));
      else
        exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Something has gone wrong.')));
  }   else
        exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Please check your inputs.')));
}
```

HTML:

```html
  <div class="fp-container">
    <h1 class="top-banner">Forgotten Password</h1>
    <h2>Forgotten your password?</h2>
    <h3>Don't worry - simply type in your email address, click <span class="btn">reset password</span> and we'll send you an email to reset your password.</h3>
    <div class="fp-form">
       <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
       <button class="btn reset-btn" type="submit" name="button">Reset Password</button>
       <br><br>
       <p id="response"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. You have not enabled SMTP so none of the settings related to SMTP will do anything. Don't try to use encryption when connecting to localhost, and don't turn off certificate verifcation. It's also unlikely you need to use authentication there either. You have misspelled several properties and methods. I recommend starting again basing your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer; it will take much less time than fixing all these mistakes.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it another go. Thanks @Synchro